# HTTP Response null

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

The HTTPResponse - res is always null...I don't know why:

```
InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent(); //I'm getting nullpointer excepetion here, because the res is null
```

Theres the `XMLDownloader` class

```
public class XMLDownloader {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccb/listarEventos.php");
    HttpResponse res = null; 
    NodeList result = null;
   // Thread t = new Thread();

    public NodeList GetNodeList() throws InterruptedException{   
        //String url = "http://fiscalartesp.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/login?";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                boolean concluido = false;

                try {
                    res = client.execute(method);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while(!concluido) {
                try{
                    URL urls;
                    urls = new URL("http://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccb/listarEventos.php");
                    InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent(); 
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(urls.openStream()));
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    result = doc.getElementsByTagName("Evento");                         
                    is.close();
                    concluido = true;
                }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.i("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                     concluido = false;
                }     

            }
        }
        }).start();
        /*
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        }).start();
        */
        while(result == null)
        {
            //Log.i("Aguardando", "Aguardando resposta");
        }


        return result;              
    }
}
```

and there's is the call

```
XMLDownloader xmlDownloader = new XMLDownloader();
NodeList list =  null;
list = xmlDownloader.GetNodeList();
```

the web service is working: you can loot the response in https://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccb/listarEventos.php

Comment: res.getEntity().getContent() will fail if there is no response and if there is no entity. Do you know which one fails exactly? I'm guessing that a request will at least return a 404 so maybe it's the entity that's missing?

Comment: @spacitron the problem is exactly that there's no response..but if you enter in url specified, the xml(web service) si running ok. Why the response is fail?

Comment: I trued running your code. I get an error saying javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate. You may want to check that.

Comment: my server now has ssl certificate. How could I do to consume the web services now?